# How to find the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\frac{17n^3-11n^2+21n-7}{33n^3+2222n}$?

Tags: limits

could somebody help me to understand how to solve equations such as:

1. Find the limit  $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $\frac{17n^3-11n^2+21n-7}{33n^3+2222n}$

Thx a lot

Comment: What do you know about limits? What happens when you divide by $n^3$?

Comment: Divide all the terms by $n^3$ and see what happens

Comment: Set $$n=\frac1h$$

Comment: By dividing I´ll get $\frac{-11n^2+21n+10}{2222n+33}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{17n^3-11n^2+21n-7}{33n^3+222n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3\left(17-\frac{11}{n}+\frac{21}{n^2}-\frac{7}{n^3}\right)}{n^3\left(33+\frac{222}{n^2}\right)}=
\frac{17}{33},$$

because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{11}{n}=0; \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{21}{n^2}=0; \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7}{n^3}=0; \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{222}{n^2}=0.$$

Comment: could you please explain how?

Comment: @ user113922: see now please

Comment: Thank you...it makes sense now :)

Comment: @ user113922: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Divide both the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{17-11(1/n)+21(1/n^2)-7(1/n^3)}{33+222(1/n^2)}=\frac{17}{33}.$$
Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}=0.$$

Comment: You are welcome!